# Can I use gl-react-image to render a local image (android) from uri?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to load an image from a local uri using the <GLImage source={{uri: "content://some path"}}/> format but it does not render. Meanwhile react native's <Image source={{uri: "content://some path"}}/> works just fine. I am using react-native 0.73.4.

I have tried:

1. To load a local asset to validate that gl-react-image can render it.  works, but is not what I want to achieve.
2. To load an image with react native's <Image source={{uri: "content://some-path"}}/> tag to validate that the permissions are not the issue.
3. To get the absolute path of the image and use that as uri - not helping.
4. To also pass width, height along with the uri - not helping.

The code is something like this:

```
<Surface style={styles.surface}>
     <GLImage
        source={{uri: "content://media/external/file/some-numbers"}}
        resizeMode="contain"
        imageSize={{height: 900, width: 1600}}
     />
</Surface>
```